# Grails: How do i select from a list of previously created objects in my view?

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp

Let's say i have the following classes:

```
package test

class Person {
    String name

    static hasMany = [stuff:Stuff]

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

and 
    package test

```
class Stuff {
    String stuff

    static belongsTo = Person

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

When i implement the view for Person i want to be able to select from a list of previously created stuff. How do i achieve that? I see that, when i use scaffolding Grails generates that drop down menu where i can do that but since i a designing my own views i would like to understand how that is done.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably good to start be reviewing the documentation for the select tag here: https://gsp.grails.org/latest/ref/Tags/select.html

A simple example to present a list of all Stuff would look like:

```
<g:select name="stuffSelect" from="${Stuff.list()}" optionKey="id" optionValue="stuff"/>
```

This should give you a dropdown of all `Stuff` in your database, displaying the String value to the user, but submitting the DB ID when the form submits.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can use the generate-all command in grails, to see what the scaffolding code looks like:
http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Command%20Line/generate-all.html

Using this command should generate Controllers, views, etc. so you can see how the scaffolded code works.   Don't worry about being able to go back to generated scaffold code, just delete the stuff created by generate-all, and grails will autogenerate it at runtime like it does now.

Comment: I was expecting to find someting like
    <g: select from...
but what i didn't quite get the code on the automatically generated view :C